# iPhone Simulator - Writing to File/Reading problems

Tags: iphone, file, ios-simulator, nsfilemanager

I have been reading alot on iPhone read/writing and I believe that everything I have is correct but for some reason it isn't working the way it should.

code is as follows

```
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"filename.rtf"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
```

I went into the folder iphone simulator documents folder for the app I am making and added that file into it as a safety measure and it is still not triggering the if statement. So for some reason it is not finding it which is making all of my writing and reading impossible. I even tried using the FileManager's createFile function and didn't get any results. If I need to post more code of something let me know but I figure if all of the above is correct it should be finding the file correctly. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Fixed. Hilariously simple mistake. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

The NSString returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` does not have a trailing slash, thus the path you are building is incorrect.  To append the filename to the use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` which will handle the path separaters correctly.

To create the filePath, try:

```
NSString *filePath =[docsDirector stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.rtf"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` instead of `stringByAppendingFormat:`. If docsDirectory does not contain a trailing slash, you will actually be creating a file called `/PATH/TO/Documentsfilename.rtf` rather than `/PATH/TO/Documents/filename.rtf`.